# What does "pat" in "pat a cake" mean?

Tags: meaning, verbs

A common nursery rhyme goes like this:

> Pat a cake, pat a cake, baker's man
> Bake me a cake as fast as you can
> Pat it and prick it and mark it with B
> And put it in the oven for baby and me.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pat-a-cake,_pat-a-cake,_baker%27s_man), "pat a cake" could be any of "pat-a-cake", "patty-cake", or "pattycake".

My question is: Is "to pat" a verb here and if so, what is its meaning?

Marriam-Webster [lists](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pat) three meanings for "to pat" as a transitive verb:

> 1: to strike lightly with a flat instrument
>  2: to flatten, smooth,
> or put into place or shape with light blows
>  3: to tap or stroke
> gently with the hand to soothe, caress, or show approval

Meaning 2 would seem to fit best. However unbaked cakes are not put in shape with blows, even light ones. Did the historic meaning of "pat", or perhaps that of "cake", change since?

Comment: What does the verb "pat" mean?

Comment: _Pat_ refers to a hand motion. It's similar to _pet_, except no living creature receives the hand motion. A physical body search is often called a "pat-down" because of the multiple patting motions of the searcher. Probably the cakes involved were something we wouldn't call "cakes" any more. This rhyme is centuries old and diets have changed.

Comment: You pat the dough as you make the cake. With the palm of your hand.

Comment: There are many different kinds of "cakes".

Comment: The question should be reopened. Here is the answer, should anyone care to use it. The origin is that people without household ovens used long ago to take their cakes to the local baker to be cooked, along with the cakes of other people. The cakes were marked (patted) by the baker to show the ownership when they all came out of the oven. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pat-a-cake,_pat-a-cake,_baker%27s_man

Comment: Regarding what type of cake it was, modern cakes such as the sponge cake were only invented in the 19th century with the popularisation of raising agents such as sodium bicarbonate. So it may have been yeasted or even unleavened. See Wikipedia for the history of baking.

Comment: Yes, understand that the term "cake" was not exclusively limited to the sort of soda-leavened, pan-baked thing we think of now when we hear the term.  More common were dough-based foods that were generally shaped by using ones hands.

Comment: Has anybody here got access to *The Oxford Dictionary of Nursery Rhymes* (Oxford University Press, 1951) edited by Iona and Peter Opie? Or indeed, any of their other books? They were considered by many to be the foremost authorities on English nursery rhymes and other children's games, and it seems likely that they will have addressed this rhyme; regrettably I have none of their books. My family and I had the privilege of Iona's friendship when we lived near her in the early 2000s.

Comment: I do have that book. Here is the relevant entry: https://ibb.co/hHM0Gn5

Answer (score 1):

The origin is that people without household ovens used long ago to take their cakes to the local baker to be cooked, along with the cakes of other people. The cakes were marked (patted) by the baker to show the ownership when they all came out of the oven.

> [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pat-a-cake,_pat-a-cake,_baker%27s_man)
> Nursery rhyme:
> *Pat-a-cake, pat-a-cake, baker's man
>
> Bake me a cake as fast as you can
>
> Roll it, pat it, and mark it with a B
>
> Throw it in the oven for Baby and me*
>
> Marking pastry or baked goods with an identifiable mark may stem from a time when households without an oven of their own could take their items to a local baker or bake house, paying to have their items finished for a small fee. Marking the pastry would have been a way to ensure the return of the proper item.

This poorly rhyming Wikipedia entry for the nursery rhyme is corrupted from a more reliable (according to my own memory and that of several commentators on my original answer) version as quoted here:

> [Nursery Rhymes](https://www.nurseryrhymes.org/pat-a-cake.html)
> *Pat-a-cake, pat-a-cake, baker's man.
>
> Bake me a cake as fast as you can
>
> Pat it, and prick it, and mark it with "B"
>
> And put it in the oven for Baby and me!*

> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pat)
> pat; patted; patting
> transitive verb
> *to strike lightly with a flat instrument*

Hence, an unbaked cake or dough would be patted with an instrument (not strictly flat in the contemporary M-W sense, but we are speaking of an old usage that goes back a long time ago to the days when many houses had no ovens, and the instrument would have made a simple pattern (such as a letter) that made a mark. The patting would have produced a mark in the unbaked item that would have been preserved through the baking process

In the example of the nursery rhyme, the cake is to be marked with "B" for “Baby”

Comments have stimulated me to add to my answer. I have left the wikipedia quotation merely to point out to other readers that it is not quite right. As regards the technicalities of cake, loaf, pastry, rolling, patting, pricking and other constituent aspects, I think we have to remember that a nursery rhyme even when first composed is bound to be a simplification of usages that have then changed over the decades or centuries. The basic point is that a pat with or without an implement will leave a mark that is retained or amplified by the baking and will serve as an identification when the item comes out of the oven.

Comment: Do you have a reference for the usage of "patting" as "marking"?

Comment: @heiner Yes, it might be self-evident but I have now added a relevant definition.

Comment: Wikipedia has chosen a really poor rendition of the rhyme! It should at least scan. I think my parents used "mark it with B" (as the question here has) and "Then into the oven for Baby and me."

Comment: One reason I find this unconvincing is that in the context of the rhyme, "pricking" presumably refers to adding an opening for the identifying mark into the cake. If there's any temporal order to the verse patting will have to be something before that.

Comment: @heiner Even today bakers and cooks are familiar with this use of pricking. The pricking of a cake to mark it refers to just that - pricking, for example with a fork. It does not refer to making an opening for insertion of anything. Even a small prick will expand in baking to make a distinct mark on top. Read, for example https://thetudortravelguide.com/2020/05/23/tudor-bread/ The techniques of pricking before baking are common and widespread: for example, see https://www.christinascucina.com/how-to-make-shortbread/

Comment: @AndrewLeach I agree with you. Perhaps I should have use "sic"!

Comment: @AndrewLeach I agree, it's very odd. The original makes much more sense. I think they're probably being hypersensitive about the word "prick". I can't think of any sort of cake that you'd roll, you do that with pastry. Also if you throw a cake in the oven it won't come out well, particularly if it's been rolled first.

Comment: Comments have stimulated me to add to my answer. I have left the wikipedia quotation merely to point out to other readers that it is not quite right.

Comment: Re: "...a pat with or without an implement will leave a mark that is retained... " - I have no evidence that 'pat' means to mark the bread. In fact, the reading of the line makes it seem like 'patting' is a separate step from marking the bread. As far as I can tell, 'pat' in that poem means 'to pat the dough so that it is flatter' and not to leave any kind of mark at all. So this sentence seems to contradict other parts of your answer.

Comment: Has anybody here got access to The Oxford Dictionary of Nursery Rhymes (Oxford University Press, 1951) edited by Iona and Peter Opie? Or indeed, any of their other books?

They were considered by many to be the foremost authorities on English nursery rhymes and other children's games, and it seems likely that they will have addressed this rhyme; regrettably I have none of their books.

My family and I had the privilege of Iona's friendship when we lived near her in the early 2000s. She was quite a character!

Answer (score -1):

OED:

> **patty-cake**, n.
>
> **Forms**:  see patty n.<sup>1</sup> and cake n. and adj<sup>2</sup>.; also 1900s– paddy-cake (U.S. regional (New Jersey)).
>
> **Etymons**: patty n., cake n. and adj.; pat-a-cake n.
>
> Etymology: Partly < patty n. + cake n. and adj., and partly alteration of pat-a-cake n.
>
> **1.** *Chiefly U.S.* *A small pie or pastry; a patty (patty n. 1).* In quot. 1788 used in the rhyme which usually accompanies the game of pat-a-cake:
>
> 1788   ‘Nurse Lovechild’ Tommy Thumb's Song Bk. 23 *Patty Cake, Patty Cake, Baker's Man; That I will Master, As fast as I can. Pricket, and Pricket, and mark it with a T; And there will be enough For Tommy and thee.*
>
> **2. U.S. = pat-a-cake** n.   *Also figurative*. Cf. earlier patty-
> cake v.
>
> 1889   Harper's Mag. June 119   *He played patty-cake steadily with
> Porley, looking at the others out of the corner of his eye.*
>
> <sup>1</sup> **patty, n.**
>
> **Etymology**: < French pâté (see pâté n.3) with substitution of -y suffix
>
> **1. A small pie or pasty.** *Now chiefly Caribbean*. Recorded earliest in pattypan n.
>
> 1660   R. May Accomplisht Cook x. 224   *Bake these quinces raw..either in tart, patty-pan, dish, or in cold butter paste.*
>
> 1710   P. Lamb Royal Cookery 75   *Your Mushroom Patty..is proper for second Course.*
>
> <sup>2</sup> **cake, n. and adj.**
>
> **Etymology**: Apparently < early Scandinavian (compare Old Icelandic kaka , Old Swedish kaka .

> **A.** n.  **I. With reference to food.**
>
> **1.a. A mass or portion of bread, usually with a rounded, flattened shape, and often baked hard on both sides as a result of being turned during the baking process.**
>
> *For use as a second element in English regional and Irish English
> compounds such as barm cake, breadcake, soda cake, stotty cake, etc.,
> see the first element.*
>
> c1225  (▸?c1200)    Hali Meiðhad (Bodl.) (1940) l. 559   *Hire cake
> bearnen o þe stan.*

**Edit to summarise**:

> patty, n.

> Origin: Perhaps of multiple origins. A borrowing from French. Perhaps also partly formed within English, by derivation. **Etymons**: French pâté  ; pat n.1, -y suffix.

> Etymology: < French pâté with substitution of -y suffix (Used to form pet names and familiar diminutives) for the ending.

> U.S. = pat-a-cake n. Cf. **earlier** patty-cake

Thus, paté > patty > pat-a

Comment: The question was about the meaning of "pat".

Comment: @HotLicks  from the above - *2. U.S. = **pat-a**-cake n. Also figurative. Cf. earlier patty- cake v.* pat-a = patty,

Comment: @Greybeard I think this is the center of the best answer, but quotes from a dictionary don't stand alone. Please give some commentary as to why you think this is the meaning of 'pat'. ('pat' is not the same as 'patty' so this necessarily needs explanation anyway). It would be nice to know if the word 'patty' is the source of "pat-a-" (probably), and if 'pat' has anything to do with 'pâté' (probably not, so confusing 'pat' and patty is a folk etymology directly in the poem).